# BaseException when trying to import azureml-train-automl-runtime in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk-python

I am trying import azureml-train-automl-runtime to do explanations from azure automl pipeline. But I am getting the below error

---

Exception ignored in: <function _Win32Helper.**del** at 0x0000021ECA3AD430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\check_win32_error\lib\site-packages\azureml\automl\runtime\shared\win32_helper.py", line 246, in **del**
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

---

Pip Freeze Output

```
adal==1.2.7
applicationinsights==0.11.10
argcomplete==2.0.0
attrs==22.1.0
azure-common==1.1.28
azure-core==1.26.0
azure-graphrbac==0.61.1
azure-identity==1.7.0
azure-mgmt-authorization==2.0.0
azure-mgmt-containerregistry==10.0.0
azure-mgmt-core==1.3.2
azure-mgmt-keyvault==10.1.0
azure-mgmt-resource==21.2.1
azure-mgmt-storage==20.0.0
azure-storage-blob==12.13.0
azure-storage-queue==12.5.0
azureml-automl-core==1.46.1.post1
azureml-automl-runtime==1.46.1.post1
azureml-core==1.46.0
azureml-dataprep==4.5.7
azureml-dataprep-native==38.0.0
azureml-dataprep-rslex==2.11.4
azureml-dataset-runtime==1.46.0
azureml-interpret==1.46.0
azureml-mlflow==1.46.0
azureml-telemetry==1.46.0
azureml-train-automl-client==1.46.0
azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.46.1.post1
azureml-train-core==1.46.0
azureml-train-restclients-hyperdrive==1.46.0
azureml-training-tabular==1.46.1.post1
backports.tempfile==1.0
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
bcrypt==4.0.1
bokeh==2.4.3
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.20.19
botocore==1.23.19
certifi @ file:///C:/b/abs_ac29jvt43w/croot/certifi_1665076682579/work/certifi
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
cloudpickle==2.2.0
colorama==0.4.5
contextlib2==21.6.0
cryptography==37.0.4
Cython==0.29.14
dask==2.30.0
databricks-cli==0.17.3
dataclasses==0.6
dill==0.3.5.1
distributed==2.30.1
distro==1.8.0
docker==5.0.3
dotnetcore2==3.1.23
entrypoints==0.4
fire==0.4.0
flatbuffers==22.9.24
fsspec==2022.10.0
fusepy==3.0.1
gensim==3.8.3
gitdb==4.0.9
GitPython==3.1.29
HeapDict==1.0.1
humanfriendly==10.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.0.0
importlib-resources==5.10.0
interpret-community==0.27.0
interpret-core==0.2.7
isodate==0.6.1
jeepney==0.8.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==0.14.1
jsonpickle==2.2.0
jsonschema==4.16.0
keras2onnx==1.6.0
knack==0.9.0
lightgbm==3.2.1
llvmlite==0.38.1
locket==1.0.0
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
ml-wrappers==0.2.2
mlflow-skinny==1.30.0
msal==1.20.0
msal-extensions==0.3.1
msgpack==1.0.4
msrest==0.7.1
msrestazure==0.6.4
ndg-httpsclient==0.5.1
nimbusml==1.8.0
numba==0.55.2
numpy==1.22.3
oauthlib==3.2.2
onnx==1.12.0
onnxconverter-common==1.6.0
onnxmltools==1.4.1
onnxruntime==1.11.1
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.1.5
paramiko==2.11.0
partd==1.3.0
pathspec==0.10.1
patsy==0.5.3
Pillow==9.2.0
pkginfo==1.8.3
pkgutil_resolve_name==1.3.10
pmdarima==1.7.1
portalocker==2.6.0
protobuf==3.20.1
psutil==5.9.3
pyarrow==9.0.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.13.0
PyJWT==2.6.0
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pyreadline3==3.4.1
pyrsistent==0.18.1
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.5
pywin32==227
PyYAML==6.0
requests==2.28.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
s3transfer==0.5.2
scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
scipy==1.5.3
SecretStorage==3.3.3
shap==0.39.0
six==1.16.0
skl2onnx==1.4.9
sklearn-pandas==1.7.0
slicer==0.0.7
smart-open==1.9.0
smmap==5.0.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
sqlparse==0.4.3
statsmodels==0.11.1
tabulate==0.9.0
tblib==1.7.0
termcolor==2.0.1
toolz==0.12.0
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.64.1
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.12
websocket-client==1.4.1
wincertstore==0.2
zict==2.2.0
zipp==3.9.0
```

Python Script

---

```
import traceback

try:
    from azureml.train.automl.runtime.automl_explain_utilities import automl_setup_model_explanations
except:
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    print(tb)
```

Error Screenshot

---

[image]

Comment: Please share the complete error traceback as well as the code snippet that raises the error.

Comment: I added the screenshot of the error and code. I am just trying to import the package in the script and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is the issue that happened. The library which needs to be imported need to be inherited to use. Run the pipeline with the inherited pattern in the code block.

```
class automl_setup_model_explanations (AutoMLExplainerSetupClass):
    pass 

return AutoMLExplainerSetupClass
```

The implementation will be made with the inheriting class. Without class inheritance we cannot use the imported model explanations.

The traceback error has occurred due to not having inheritance.

Comment: Ok, this means that it is problem with azure package and not from my side. I will see what can be done for that.